# Populating a webpage using AJAX from data over two pages

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to populate a select box using AJAX that gets its data from two pages.
`mainPage.jsp` has the following code..

```
<td>Product</td>
        <td><select name="selProduct" id="selProduct"  onchange='loadXMLDoc();' >
            <option value="-1"> Select Product</option>
            <option value="0"> JSA Three Wheelers</option>
            <option value="1"> Rotavators</option>
            <option value="2"> ACE Tractors</option>
            <option value="3"> BCS Reaper Binder</option>
            <option value="4"> Lubi Pumps</option>
            <option value="5"> New Golden Punjab Thresers</option>

          </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>
            <div id="myDiv">

            </div>



        </td>
        </tr>
```

The function `loadXMLDoc()` is as

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}
var sel=byId('selProduct');
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","NewFile.jsp?str="+sel.value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The file `NewFile.jsp` is as

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <%  //String selProduct= request.getParameter("str");
  //int valProduct= Integer.parseInt(selProduct);
  String sel= request.getParameter("str");
  int valProduct= Integer.parseInt(sel);


 %>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc1()
{
  function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}
  var selModel=byId('selModel');
  alert(selModel.value);
  var selProduct=<%=valProduct%>;

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  { 
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("divRate").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    //document.getElementsByName(txtTest).Text=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","selPrice.jsp?selProduct="+selProduct+"&"+"selModel="+selModel.value,true);
   xmlhttp.send();

}
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>


<select name="selModel1" id="selModel" onchange='loadXMLDoc1();'>
<option  value="-1">select Model </option>
 <%if(valProduct==0){ %>

 <option value="1">Victory 1000 DIII Passenger</option>
 <option value="2">Victory plus 1000 DIII Passenger </option>
 <option value="3">Victory 1000 DIII Loader </option>
 <option value="4">Victory 1000 DIII Chassis </option>
 <option value="5">Victory 1360 DIII Passenger </option>
 <option value="6">Victory 1360 DIII Window Dx Passenger </option>
 <option value="7">Victory 1360 DIII Loader </option>
 <%}
 else if (valProduct==1){%>


<option value="1">SRT-6/540 (SEMI CHAMPION)</option>
<option value="2">SRT-5.5/1000 (SEMI CHAMPION)</option>
<option value="3">SRT-6/1000 (SEMI CHAMPION)</option>
<option value="4">SRT-7/1000 (SEMI CHAMPION)</option>
<option value="5">SRT-5.5/MS LIGHT SERIES (1.65/1000)</option>
<option value="6">SRT-6/MS LIGHT SERIES (1.85/1000)</option>
<option value="7">SRT-7/MS LIGHT SERIES (2.05/1000)</option>
 <%} 
 else if (valProduct==2){%>


 <option value="1">Ace Tractors</option>
 <option value="2">Ace Tractors</option>
 <%} 
 else if (valProduct==3){%>


<option value="1">Complete Reaper Binder</option>
<option value="2">Tractor Mounted Reaper Binder</option>
<%} 
else if (valProduct==4){
%>

 <option value="1">MDH-50A (HP-0.5) Self Priming</option>
 <option value="2">MDH-27A (HP-0.5) Self Priming</option>
 <option value="3">MDH-27ASF (HP-1.0) Self Priming</option>
 <option value="4">MCJ051SP (HP-0.5) Shallow Well Jet</option>
 <option value="5">MCJ101SP (HP-1.0) Shallow Well Jet</option>
<%} %>
</select>
<div id="divRate"> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also `selPrice.jsp` is as .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<% String selModel= request.getParameter("selModel");
String selProduct=request.getParameter("selProduct");
//int valModel=1;
int valProduct= Integer.parseInt(selProduct);
valModel= Integer.parseInt(selModel);
System.out.println(selModel);
System.out.println(valProduct);
System.out.println(valModel);
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("name"));
%>

<%if(valProduct ==0 && valModel==1 ){ %>
 <input type="text" value="173000" readonly="readonly">
<%} 
else if(valProduct ==0 && valModel==2 ){ %>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="183000">
<%}
else if (valProduct==1 && valModel==1){%>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="400000" >


<%} 
else if (valProduct==1 && valModel==2){%>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="450000">
<%} %>


</body>
</html>
```

This should work like I select Product, based on its value, the models are populated from 
`NewFile.jsp`. This is working fine. In  `NewFile.jsp`, on selecting the model, the price is to be populated using the values `selProduct` and `selModel`. When I am running `NewFile.jsp`, this price is getting populated but when I am running `mainFile.jsp`, `selModel` is being passed as `null` to `selPrice.jsp` from `NewFile.jsp`. So I am getting stuck there.I might be doing something wrong here but I am unable to spot it. So any help would be great here.

Thanks

Comment: where is e ? you are passing to function to byId ???where do you get it to pass ? `function loadXMLDoc()
{
function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}`

Comment: e is generic. whenever an id is passed into byID(id), it returns the value.

Comment: Yeah i can see from ur code but it seems to value in e check for it.as u are only calling loadxmldoc function only you will get value in this and i think u hvnt received that

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways that you can use.

For example you can store in a temp database table, the record you need or 
a better way could be using the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem("ID", MyVar);
```

then use

```
var MyID= localStorage.getItem("ID");
```

to read the value from another page

Hope my English is clear.